# Naturality of primary obstruction under fiber-preserving maps

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, fibration, obstruction-theory

Let $B$ be a path-connected CW complex, and let $p:E\to B$ and $p':E'\to B$ be fibrations. Let $f:E'\to E$ be a fiber-preserving map, which therefore induces a map of fibers $\bar{f}:F'\to F$.

Let us suppose that both $F'$ and $F$ are $(q-1)$-connected ($q>1$). Then the primary obstructions to sectioning $p$ and $p'$ are cohomology classes
$$
o(p)\in H^{q+1}(B;\pi_q(F)),\qquad  o(p')\in H^{q+1}(B;\pi_q(F')).
$$

Here are my questions:

1. Is it true that $o(p)=\bar{f}_*o(p')$? Here $\bar{f}_*$ denotes the coefficient homomorphism induced by the map $\bar{f}_\sharp:\pi_q(F')\to \pi_q(F)$ of $\pi_1(B)$-modules.
2. If so, can we give a reference?
3. Is something more general true, for a fiber-preserving map $f:E'\to E$ covering a map $g:B'\to B$?

Comment: Probably taking a look at the construction of o(p) might help?

Comment: I agree with @user43326, it follows from the construction using a cellular cocycle that 1. is correct and that in 3. we have $g^*o(p)=\overline{f}_*o(p')$.